# Create object from es6 and using in js file with openlayers map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, openlayers

i want to create own API, i created class and object with es6 and using javascript core.

when i ran this code with npm, got this error;**Uncaught ReferenceError: mapper is not defined**

Where do you think I get an error?

***index.js; OpenLayers's function in code***

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

window.onload = config;
let mapper;

function config() {
    mapper = new IMapper();
}

export class IMapper{
    constructor(){
    }

   initMap () {
        const map = new Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0
            })
        });
    }
}
```

***index.html; called es6 code in js core and i got this error***

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using Parcel with OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapper.initMap();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***package.json***

```
 {
  "name": "ol-parcel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example using OpenLayers with Parcel",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "parcel index.html",
  "build": "parcel build --public-url . *.html *.js"
  },
    "dependencies": {
    "ol": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.9.4"
  }    
}
```

Thank you for responses...

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call your `config` function.

```
window.onload = config();
```

Comment: Probably because it's this line that's broken: `mapper.initMap();`  You should not rely on mapper being defined in the static markup.  You should do that in your component instead where you can control what is loaded when.

Comment: Hi @jmargolisvt, I don't think this is the problem. With `window.onload = config();` they would just assign `undefined` to `window.onload`, because the `config` function doesn't return anything. My bet is that `window.onload` is called by the browser *after* the inline JS code `mapper.initMap();` is run.

Comment: Agreed @PatrickHund , that's what I was trying to say in my second comment.